# split + substring + tolist c# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to build my function in a single Linq expression.

- What I have: A string with values separated by comma:

`var values = "AA1234,AA2345,BB2345"`

- What i need: A list of this values but only the first two characters ('AA,BB,CC')

Then I created this simple function to do it:

```
var finalList = new List<string>();
var splitedList = previousString.Split(',').ToList();
foreach (var s in splitedList )
{
    finalList .Add(s.Substring(0,2));
}
```

Then I got the result, also i tried to convert to mostly linq that i can and this is the result:

```
var splitedList = previousString.Split(',').ToList();
var finalList = splitedList.Select(s=> s.Substring(0, 2)).ToList();
```

And also the result is fine.

But exist any way to simplify this in one single call?

I tried some commands but they didn't work:

```
var finallist = previousString.Split(',').ToString().Substring(0,2).ToList();
var finallist = previousString.Split(',').ToString().Take(2);
var finallist = previousString.Split(',').ToString().Take(2).ToList();
```

Maybe is just not possible,

Thanks For all.

Comment: Why did you add a `.ToString()`? You don't have it in the query that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `ToList()` if there's no particular reason for it.

```
var values = "AA1234,AA2345,BB2345";

var splitedList = values
  .Split(',')
  .Select(s => s.Substring(0, 2))
  .ToList();
```

`ToList()` will create a `List<string>`, while `Split(',')` will generate a `string[]`. Both implement `IEnumerable`, which makes the `ToList()` unecessary, as Select() only requires an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var finalList = previousString.Split(',').Select(s => s.Substring(0, 2)).ToList();
```